# Searching a Data Frame in R

Tags: r, search, indexing, dataframe

How do I go about searching a `data.frame` based on multiple criteria? For instance, I have a `data.frame` with columns such as `Date`, `Time`, `Item`, `Value`, and I then want to search the `data.frame` where I have `Date = 1/2/2010`, `Time = 5pm`, `Item = Car`, `Value = 5`, is there a function that will allow me to do that? More importantly, how do I obtain the row index of the data frame which has these values?

For example, say all these values are in the third row of the data frame, is there a function which will search the data frame row by row and then output that index is 3?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sounds like you have a question about performing a query. If you are familiar with `dplyr` package, you'll find functions such as `select` that can help. However, you should be able accomplish what you need just by using the `base` and `stats` packages.

For instance, given a data frame, you should extract the row indices that match your criteria. You can accomplish this by using the `which` function:

```
indices <- which(data$Date == "1/2/2010" & data$Time == "5pm" & data$Item =="Car" & data$Value == 5)
```

Then you'd be ready to subset

```
data_subset <- data[indices, ]
```

I hope the above hypothetical example would help you get to the answer you need.

Answer (score 3):

You may use "which" as the following code:

```
df <- data.frame(cbind(Date = '1/2/2010', Time = '5pm', Item = 'Car', Value = 50000))
new <- data.frame(cbind(Date = '1/3/2010', Time = '6am', Item = 'keys', Value = 100))
df <- rbind(df, new)

searchIndex1 <- function(dd, tt, itm, val){
which(df$Date==dd & df$Time== tt & df$Item ==itm & df$Value == val)
}
searchIndex1(dd='1/3/2010', tt='6am', itm='keys', val=100)
```

It will return the Index number 2.

Or you may use "filter":

```
searchIndex2 <- function(dd, tt, itm, val){
  df.with.index <- mutate(df, IDX = 1:n())
  result <- filter(df.with.index,(Date==dd & Time== tt & Item ==itm & Value == val))$IDX
}

searchIndex2(dd='1/2/2010', tt='5pm', itm='Car', val=50000)
```

It will return Index 1.